# Get Value out of Try/Catch exception?

Tags: java, android

I'm try to create a simple android application for currency exchange and i got stuck when i got to this try and catch. I wanna get the value of rate from inside the try and catch and use it, but im am unable to figure out how this is possible or if it is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        String exchange = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + FROM + "&to=" + TO + "&q=1";

        double RATE = 0;

            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = readJsonFromUrl(exchange);
                for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i ++)
                    RATE = json.getDouble("v");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            total.setText(String.valueOf(RATE*AMOUNT));
```

Comment: What is the challenge? You need to elaborate more. And why do u need a for loop here?

Comment: So are you getting exceptions then?  From what I see, if you get any exception you'll have 0 for RATE, which could be seen as okay, since you don't have data to work with.  (You're also overwriting RATE every time through the loop, so only the last "v" is evaluated.)

Comment: Im lopping to get the value of the key 'v' which is the rate of exchnage, the loop only goes once since length is 1, becaue the JSON file have only one dictionarie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double RATE = 0; // initialize RATE

JSONObject json;
try {
    // do something
     RATE = json.getDouble("v"); // calculate values for RATE, if try fail 
                                 //before assign value RATE will be 0
 } catch (IOException e) {

 } catch (JSONException e) {

 }

 total.setText(String.valueOf(RATE*AMOUNT)); // so still RATE 0 and 
                                             //wrong calculation
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double RATE = 0; // initialize RATE

JSONObject json;
try {
    // do something
     RATE = json.getDouble("v"); // calculate values for RATE, if try fail 
                                 //before assign value RATE will be 0
 } catch (IOException e) {

 } catch (JSONException e) {

 }finnally
{
   \\ Set Rate Here
}
```